# WinForm Simple Raw Bitmap Font Writing?

Tags: winforms, fonts

I need to write in a form using a bitmap font at a specific point size, without having Windows do any antialiasing or otherwise "helping" the display of the text. The reason is that the text will be saved out as a bitmap for display on a low-resolution display (eg a Netduino-driven bitmap with space for 120 pixels wide and 40 pixels high) , so if I want a black "A" on the screen I can't have grey pixels added in and arund the letters.

I need to use a font like this

http://robey.lag.net/2010/01/23/tiny-monospace-font.html

Although I know Windows doesn't do BDF I included that as a reference to the kind of no-nonsense super small typeface that I need to use in Windows.

Using C#, Franework 4.5.2, what can I do to make .NET emit a typeface as a pure unscaled bitmap?

I built a bitmap using the "Tiny" TrueType font at 6 point. Notice in the generated bitmap image that the text is all not pure white, although I specified it that way.

[image]

```
using (var gb = Graphics.FromImage(mybitmap))
{
gb.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
gb.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
gb.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
gb.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
gb.TextContrast = 0;
gb.Clear(colorbg);
var fontSize = Convert.ToSingle(6);
var nowFont = new Font( myfont , fontSize, GraphicsUnit.Pixel );
TextRenderer.DrawText(gb, "pack my box..." , nowFont , new Point(0, 0), colorforeground);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the Graphics.TextRenderingHint property to `TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit`.  If the font has no TrueType hinting at all then SingleBitPerPixel is probably your preferred choice.  Either renders text without any anti-aliasing.